# ¿Como hacer que al seleccionar una canción y después otra la primera se pare?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un reproductor MP3 con Windows Forms y al seleccionar una canción (con un comboBox) se reproduce pero al elegir otra canción no deja de reproducirse, ya intente con el método stop pero solo funcionaba cuando la primera canción comenzaba y la demas seguian en serie.

```
     private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (comboBox.Text)
            {
                case "A World Away":                        
                        cancion = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
                        cancion.URL = Application.StartupPath + @"\Canciones\Away.mp3";
                        cancion.controls.play();
                        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/TEMP/Documents/Escuela/Programacion/Reproductor/" +
                     "Reproductor/Reproductor/bin/Debug/Canciones/Away.jpg");
                        labArtista.Text = "Inukshuk";
                   break;

                case "Tu Falta de Querer":

                        cancion = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
                        cancion.URL = Application.StartupPath + @"\Canciones\Querer.mp3";
                        cancion.controls.play();
                        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/TEMP/Documents/Escuela/Programacion/Reproductor/" +
                     "Reproductor/Reproductor/bin/Debug/Canciones/Querer.jpg");
                        labArtista.Text = "Mon Lafarte";
                    break;

                case "Kimi to Kare to Boku to Kanojo to":

                       cancion = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
                        cancion.URL = Application.StartupPath + @"\Canciones\Kimi.mp3";
                        cancion.controls.play();
                        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/TEMP/Documents/Escuela/Programacion/Reproductor/" +
                     "Reproductor/Reproductor/bin/Debug/Canciones/Fairy.jpg");
                        labArtista.Text = "Breathe";
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: \n" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Has probado a poner `cancion.controls.stop();` al principio de tu método `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged`?